# How can I pass a parameter of MutableState<String> to a function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I hope to invoke `fun EditTextDialog(...)` in Code A. Normally I can use Code B to invoke it.

At present, I have wrapped many parameters into `class ParameterLineState`, so I hope to pass parameter to  `fun EditTextDialog(...)` via the class `ParameterLineState`.

But Code C is wrong, how can design `class ParameterLineState` and let me pass parameter to `fun EditTextDialog(...)`  ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun EditTextDialog(  
    iniEditFieldContent: MutableState<String> = remember{ mutableStateOf("")}
) {

}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {   
    val editFieldContent = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
  
    EditTextDialog(       
        iniEditFieldContent = editFieldContent
    )
}
```

**Code C**

```
@Composable
fun HandleDialogs(
    parLineState: ParameterLineState = rememberParameterLineState()   
) {

    EditTextDialog(     
        iniEditFieldContent = parLineState.iniContent    // It cause error
    )
}

class ParameterLineState private constructor() {
    var iniContent by mutableStateOf("")
          private set

    fun set_IniContent(value:String) {
        iniContent = value
    }

    companion object {
        val instance: ParameterLineState by lazy { ParameterLineState() }
    }
}


@Composable
fun rememberParameterLineState(): ParameterLineState {
    return remember {
        ParameterLineState.instance
    }
}
```

Comment: can you not read the state and pass it as a param to compose function

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that Code B is only way to pass `iniEditFieldContent: MutableState<String> = remember{ mutableStateOf("")}` parameter?

Comment: editFieldContent .value can be read and pass the value to another composable. read this https://dev.to/zachklipp/remember-mutablestateof-a-cheat-sheet-10ma